# Swift Dynamic CollectionView Height: CollectionView inside CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have collectionView(list of items) inside another collectionview(list of items) and base on inside collectionview's content size we have set that to parent collection(cell)

Below is the scenario
`Parent CollectionView <br/> // **Parent Collection**`

`CollectionViewCell`

`Child CollectionView // **child Collection**`

`CollectionViewCell`

I have to set Content Size(child) to parent CollectionView Height

we don't want to use observer inside collectionview cell for contentSize changed

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you show us your code how far have you done or where you stuck at?

Comment: why this question downgraded?? @HabinLama

Comment: @VishalDesai - please review [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used the same logic which is described under below sample code:

https://github.com/pgpt10/DynamicHeightCollectionView

[Note: Take care of font utilised for cell's label and storyboard label font size.